# I am receiving an OSError while working through an online tutorial and I am unable to figure it out myself

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently receiving a list of errors that the person in the tutorial didn't receive and I am unable to figure it out since I am new to coding. The issue im getting is when im trying to load in a previously run file saved as .h5.

The specific issues I'm getting is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/ajpvi/Desktop/Python, pycharm learning project/Python Basics/CIFAR-10/Protobuf_Creation_Script.py", line 23, in 
model = load_model(filepath='Image_Classifier.h5')

File "C:\Users\ajpvi\Desktop\Python, pycharm learning project\python 3.8.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 211, in load_model
loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)

File "C:\Users\ajpvi\Desktop\Python, pycharm learning project\python 3.8.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 111, in parse_saved_model
raise IOError("SavedModel file does not exist at: %s/{%s|%s}" %
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: Image_Classifier.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

The specifc lines they are refer to are below:

model = load_model(filepath='Image_Classifier.h5')

loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)

raise IOError("SavedModel file does not exist at: %s/{%s|%s}" %

Comment: Edit this post to inlcude the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 I would use pathlib's Path() to specify the location of the file

```
from pathlib import Path
model = load_model(filepath=Path('./Image_Classifier.h5'))
```

... Would mean it was in the current working directory.

But the file has to be there.  This error means Image_Classifier.h5 doesn't exist or isn't where you thought the program was referencing.

So there are a couple of fixes.
the first fix is to define the location of the file explicitly.
model = load_model(filepath=Path('C:\Users\ajpvi\Desktop\Python, pycharm learning project<directory path>\Image_Classifier.h5'))

The second fix is only if you don't want to specify the locations of files (please go with option number one if you are learning python). Then you can make sure to run it from the same directory the file Image_Classifier.h5 is in.  (in terminal change directory from where you are to the directory Image_Classifier.h5 is in and start Jupyter notebook or run the python script from there.

Comment: Following your changes it now gives me this error. SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: you did put in the location of the file right?  (change <directory path> to the location)  Or the file Image_Classifier.h5 might be unreadable.

Comment: I didnt but than I did after seeing your comment but it still giving me the same error the \a is highlighting a different color than the rest of the filepath

Comment: I've answered the question you could give me an upvote.  Add your new code to the question under a heading called "Edit" and explain the new problem.